# Error 30 during Linux installation on Virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've got some issue during installation of Linux on Virtualbox. I tried install a few different versions of distos (like Elementary, Mint) and repeadetly I getting `error 30 read-only file system`. Live versions works fine but I would prefer installed one. 
I'm using newest version of Virtualbox for macOS High Sierra. Have you guys have some tip how to resolve this problem? Maybe I do something wrong while setting up VM?

My VM configuration:
type: **Linux**, version: **Other Linux 64-bit**, with Virtual Drive (VDI, dynamically allocated)

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this problem by changing configuration to Linux, Ubuntu 64-bit and dynamically allocated VHD.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  This would be more helpful to others with a similar problem if you could expand the answer to elaborate on how to do it.